# Command terminated with exit code 7

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have 3 node K8S cluster, I have created 3 replica pods on which application - app1 is running on all the pods, I have established service by running service yaml file and I can see my cluster-Ip created by running kubectl get service

When I try to do curl from one of the node I am getting " curl: (7) Failed to connect - failed to connect"
 when I try to curl inside the pod I am getting ... "command terminated with exit code 7"

Commands Ran:

> kubectl  run kubia --image=kubia --port=8080 --generator=run/v1
>
> kubectl scale rc kubia --replicas=3

Manifest file used:

> apiVersion: v1
>   kind: Service
>   metadata:
>     name: kubia
>   spec:
>     ports:
>     - port: 80
>       targetPort: 8080.
>     selector:
>       app: kubia

Can any body help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Please can you share your manifest (yaml) files? I would like to check how did you implemented your pods and services.

Comment: Watney - This is the manifest file , I have used to create service                                                                                  apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kubia
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: kubia

Comment: Please, update your question with all manifest files your are using. Pod, Deployment, Service and so on.

Comment: Updated Watney.

Comment: Can you also add your deployment YAML file?  (Especially the `labels:` for the pod are important.)  If you `kubectl describe service kubia`, does it list any endpoints?  What's the actual `curl` command you're running, and where are you running it from?

Comment: Thanks Watney, David for your time , I just fixed the issue....                                                    solution : selection should be run:kubia instead of app:kubia

Comment: I  just fixed the issue....                                                                                     solution : selector should be run:kubia instead of app:kubia                                            how I resolved  -- kubectl describe kubia and observed all the fields and found selector should be run instead of app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution :  In yaml file - selector should be run: kubia instead of app: kubia, deleted the old service and again created new service , I am able to do curl on the internal ip from the pod. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 2 Node (+ Control Plane Node) Kubernetes cluster in my VirtualBox. All of the VMs that are the part of this cluster are running CentOS. I had the same error when i tried to hit my Service endpoint IP using curl command inside one of my pods that is running on worker nodes (command terminated with exit code 7).

Solution: Firewall was up and running, and the port 80 that Service is listening on was not open. After i changed firewall configuration to accept 80/TCP traffic on my Control Plane Node, the curl command from inside the container was able to hit the service IP.

Worker Node to Control plane Node request over 80/TCP was approved.

Comment: All my pods that are behind the Services are labeled app: my-pods-label and the label selector in the Service YAML definition is referencing that label (my-pods-label) 

spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80 
    targetPort: 8080 
  selector:
    app: my-pods-label